# Limit Proc Means Output to Complete Rows only

Tags: sas

I have a simple proc means procedure and I wish to limit the output to complete rows only.

```
   data test_dat;
        input group $ subgroup $ time variable1 variable2;
    cards;
    A xxxx 1 100 2.50
    A xxxx 2 200 2.50
    A xxxx 3 300 2.50 
    A xxxx 4 100 3.00
    A zzzz 1 500 1.00
    A zzzz 2 450 1.00
    A zzzz 3 700 1.50
    A zzzz 4 600 1.50
    B yyyy 1 200 4.00
    B yyyy 2 100 5.00
    B yyyy 3 300 4.00
    B yyyy 4 250 5.00
    ;
    run;

    proc means data=test_dat mean sum;
        class group subgroup;
        var variable2 variable1;
        output out=stuffout(drop=_type_ _freq_ dropme ohheidropme2plz) mean=variable2_mean dropme sum=ohheidropme2plz variable1_sum;
    run;
```

By default, proc means is giving me 9 rows of output, when I only want three (rows 7-9).  I know that I can do another data step to eliminate these rows, but know that there has to be a more elegant way.  (ps--it won't always be rows 7-9, so that won't work as a general solution).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like what you're looking for is the proc means `nway` option. See here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146729.htm

```
proc means data=test_dat mean sum nway;
        class group subgroup;
        var variable2 variable1;
        output out=stuffout(drop=_type_ _freq_ dropme ohheidropme2plz) mean=variable2_mean dropme sum=ohheidropme2plz variable1_sum;
    run;
```

You could also achieve the same results by using the types or ways statements.

Here you could use `ways 2;` , which is saying show all combinations of possible **pairs** of your class variables. The keyword nway simply specifies that ways = n, where n is the number of class variables you have. By default, proc means includes all possible rows that represent totals (e.g. sum and mean for a given value of your group variable, irrespective of subgroup variable). `Ways 2` specifies that you are interested only in those rows that have exactly two of your class variables, which in this case is all of them.

Comment: Another interesting option is types [(http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000222729.htm)], which allows you to chose all possible variables combination

Comment: Thanks Nate.  That's exactly what I needed.  The nway option works better for me than ways 2, because I won't always know how many class variables there are (loaded by macro).  I had tried doing a where statement by _type_ but not general enough.  Thanks guys.